# How to reverse a string where the capitalization is reversed with only specified characters, and others remain unchanged

Tags: java

```
    String myStr = this.myString;
    String output = "";
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < myStr.length(); i++) {
        if (arg.contains(myStr.charAt(i) + "") ) 


    this.myCustomString.setString("abc, XYZ; 123.");
    assertEquals("aBC, xyz; 123.", this.myCustomString.reverse("bcdxyz@3210."));
```

error: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <aBC, xyz; 123.> but was: <aBC, XYZ; 123.>

I am stuck on how to handle the Uppercase word, I have no idea, can someone help me with this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are checking, in the `contains(...)` method, if the characters is among the ones you want to reverse, but the `contains(...)` method is case sensitive, so when looking for `Y` it doesn't find it, because it only has a lowercase `y`.

So, without discussing any other matters of the code, which could be improved, to make it work just change in the `if` this:

```java
arg.contains(myStr.charAt(i) + "")
```

for this:

```java
arg.contains(Character.toLowerCase(myStr.charAt(i)) + ""
```